# Security issue with angular build dependent packages angular

Tags: security, package.json, angular12

We are facing vulnerability issue with angular 12.24 when scanned with black duck tool.

Below are the packages with issues.

1. PostCss - 7.0.36. Recommended -8.3.6
2. url-parse - 1.5.1 Recommended -1.5.3
3. glob-parent - 3.1.0 Recommended -6.0.1
4. einaros/ws - 6.2.2 Recommended -8.0.0

How can I update these versions as these are dependent packages of core packages installed.

Tried solutions

npm audit fix - Not working

Updated to latest angular version - Not working.

Updated package-lock.json - Getting overwritten on npm i.

Thanks in advance.